# Boolean test for connectivity in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am studying Angular 7 by decomposing [this example app](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app).

An Angular 7 app is testing connectivity by adding a boolean property to a class definition and then using `ngIf` to test for the boolean property in the view.  What specific connectivity is the boolean property testing for?

The following undesired result is being printed in the browser instead of the desired content.

```
`: )`
```

As you can see, the following code extracted from [src/app/app.component.html](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html), the following logic prints the above `: )` when the `isOnline` property of `AppComponent` is not true.

```
<div>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet *ngIf="isOnline;else isOffline"></router-outlet>
  <ng-template #isOffline>
    <div>
        <span>:&nbsp;)</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

As you can see from the definition of [app.component.ts](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts), the `` boolean is defined as follows:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  isOnline: boolean;

}
```

Comment: `isOnline` is `undefined` as you didn't assign a value, which is why the `ng-template` is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your code, it worked. You can `{{isOnline}}` to check value.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngif-else-2